# ember data array UI not updating on pushObject

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a list of product-tag that I fetch for my model.

Route:

```
model: function() {
  return {
    product_tags: this.store.find('product-tag', {merchant: merchId})
  }
}
```

I have a component that adds tags to the model, however when after I create the record and push it into the model (as suggested on other posts) my UI still isn't updating.

```
addTag: function(name) {
  tag = this.store.createRecord('product-tag', {
    name: name
  });
  this.model.product_tags.toArray().addObject(tag);  

  tag.save();
}


//model merchant.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user_id: DS.attr('number'),
  product_tags: DS.hasMany('product-tag', {async: true})
});

//model product-tag.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
 merchant: DS.belongsTo('merchant'),
 name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of ember and ember data are you using? The entire approach  here is wrong

Comment: ember: 1.13.7
ember-data -  "1.13.8"

Comment: can you add your `product-tag` model and your `merchant` model, what is their relationship?

Comment: Where are you getting `merchId` from?

Comment: Uhm he's probably using a nested route and sending it via a helper. e.g "link.to"

Comment: merchId is from params, yes it's a nested route.

Comment: Can you add your related router code please.

Comment: did you try `this.get('model.product_tags').pushObject(tag)`? why are you adding the tag before the save is resolved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should make it array in the route, so u can use it always afterwards like u want. Your calling toArray() which makes a new Array instance, then your model is not hooked to the array u just made.

```
  model: function() {
      return {
        product_tags: this.store.query('product-tag', {merchant: merchId}).then(function(pt) {
           return pt.toArray(); 
        });
      }
    }

   var x = this.get('model.product_tags') === model's p_t // true
   var y = this.get('model.product_tags').toArray() === model's p_t // false
```

Later on just do

```
addTag: function(name) {
  this.get('store').createRecord('product-tag', {
    name: name
  }).save().then(function(saved){ 
     this.get('model.product_tags').pushObject(saved);
  }.bind(this);  
}
```

Comment: No, just no, there is absolutely no reason to make the model into an array, you should also camelCase your variables. `product-tag` and `tag` should have a one-to-many relationship, `this.store.createRecord('product-tag', { product: product, tag: tag}` is more than enough, and you shouldn't use find with query params there's [query](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_query) for that, what you have should be throwing warnings and jshint errors

Comment: These are not my variables, also im not questoning his way of building the models and queries to backend. Im just here to make this thing work the way he wanted it. You're right about store.find. changed it to query.

Comment: The way he wants it is horrible wrong, you shouldn't promote it.

Comment: my model returns a  "<DS.PromiseArray:ember755>" which i believe is immutable. What is proper way of doing this? besides using toArray() and then setting my model the array?

Comment: @imahungry not immutable, we're using this approach in some places.

Comment: @imahungry Just realised that saving was done wrong. updated it for now. should work

Comment: @imahungry calling `.toArray` returns a new array, so you're adding the new tag to a new array and then not doing anything with that array.

Comment: @locks we kinda figured it out before.