# This.get(‘model’).addObjects(records); throw exception “Uncaught TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function”

Tags: ember.js

Friends I need help, after updating to Ember 2.X, my infinite scroll stopped working. On reaching page end, I query store to get new records:

```
 load_more: function(){
 var self = this;
  this.get("store").query("actor",{pg: 1}}).then(function(records) {

    self.get('model').addObjects(records); // this throw excepton 

  }
}
```

This was working perfectly but now `self.get('model').addObjects(records);` throw exception `"Uncaught TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function" in record-array.js at line 86 "return internalModel && internalModel.getRecord()"`.

I tried using `self.get('model').pushObjects(records);` but it also give same error, please help

Comment: Take a look at this answer that got downvoted. I'm sure you have the same issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964664/ember-data-array-ui-not-updating-on-pushobject/32964755#32964755

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue.. try doing

```
self.get('model').toArray().pushObjects(records)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is on your controller.  You could try using `Ember` get, which better used when fetching items on promises:

```
load_more: function(){
  Ember.get(this, "store").query("actor",{ pg: 1 }}).then((records) => {
    Ember.get(this, 'model').addObjects(records);
  }
}
```

Ember 2.x should give you access to the latest version of babel, which means you can use `=>` functions (and don't have to do `var self = this` as it will do it for you).